# How to use neverthrow with async/await through the call hierarchy the proper way

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have just recently started to use neverthrow. Unfortunately there is not so much documentation regarding the usage available for it yet.

I am currently replacing my pure Promise structure by ResultAsync. I am not sure, if I am using it the right way though.

As an example, I do have an initialization function, that will call two other async functions which return ResultAsync.
**My goal is to keep using async/await**. It feels a little bit strange however, that I have to wrap all my code that is calling other ResultAsyncs inside a promise and then a ResultAsync again.

Is there something I'm missing here or should do differently?

```
public init(): ResultAsync<null, AppError> {
        const initInner = async (): Promise<null> => {
            const oidcConfResult = await this.retrieveOidcConf();
            if (oidcConfResult.isErr()) {
                throw oidcConfResult.error;
            }
            this.oidcConf = oidcConfResult.value;

            const keyResult = await this.retrieveKey();
            if (keyResult.isErr()) {
                throw keyResult.error
            }
            this.key = keyResult.value;
            return null;
        }
        return ResultAsync.fromPromise(initInner(), e => e as AppError)
    }
```

```
private retrieveOIDCConf(): ResultAsync<OIDCConf, AppError> {
        return ResultAsync.fromPromise(
            axios
                .get(confService.oauthConfig.oidcConfURI)
                .then(res => {
                    if (validateOIDCConf(res.data)) {
                        logger.info(`successfully retrieved OIDC configuration from ${confService.oauthConfig.oidcConfURI}`)
                        return res.data
                    } else {
                        logger.error(`OIDC configuration returned in unexpected format from ${confService.oauthConfig.oidcConfURI}`)
                        throw new AppError({
                            ...
                        })
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    logger.error(`Could not retrieve OIDC configuration. from ${confService.oauthConfig.oidcConfURI}`, e)
                    throw new AppError({
                        ...
                    })
                }), (e) => e as AppError)

    }
```

Comment: Do you actually need to wrap it in a promise? I've not worked with `neverthrow` but it seems like you can just `return uidcConfResult` if it is an error, not `throw uidcConfResult.error`. This seems like the very point of the library, you never throw anything, instead you return objects with success/error states. In data fetching function as well, you probably shouldn't `throw new AppError` but instead `return err(new AppError(...))`

Comment: As per my understanding, you need to when using ResultAsync (https://github.com/supermacro/neverthrow/wiki/Basic-Usage-Examples#asynchronous-api / https://github.com/supermacro/neverthrow#asynchronous-api-resultasync) as you can only/are supposed to construct it from a Promise. And since I am inside a Promise, I have to throw (or use reject in a more verbose code).

in init() I could call retrieveOidcConf() outside of a Promise ofc, but then I cannot use await, because the outer function must be async to use await. And when its async, it has to return a Promise...

Comment: It seems like `errAsync` function and `fromPromise` are just interfaces that let you convert code that doesn't use `neverthrow` to `neverthrow`. If some function from a different library returns a promise that can throw an error, then you wrap it in `fromPromise`. In your code, however, you *never throw* anything, neither in promise nor anywhere else, you only return error/success result, that's the point of the library

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I see your point, and I can improve retrieveOIDCConf() that way.
Could you clarify, how you would implement init() without using a Promise(and in consequence being forced to throw or reject) though? According to neverthrows documentation, I need to await or .then a ResultAsync. And when I do that, there is no way around an async function and therefore returning a Promise (in the code above initInner), or is there?

Comment: Yes, `init` will have to be an async function. Returning promise is also an option, but it will probably be very inconvenient, because if you try to chain `then` calls, you will always have to check whether the result from previous one is not an error, whereas with async function you can just return error result right away.  No `fromPromise` needed, however, You cannot do it without async functions or promises because of the very nature of promises. If one thing is async, then everyone who uses it must be async too, whether it uses `neverthrow` or not